# HTML/CSS: Creating a Chatbox. Chatbox doesn't show scrollbar when chat bubble container that scale upward cause an overflow

Tags: html, css

Sorry for a vague title, my English vocabulary is pretty limited.

I'm trying to do a chatbox for my website (work kinda like Facebook Messenger). What I have are:

A chatbox:

```
.chatbox {
   width:500px;
   height:500px;
   max-height:500px;
   display: block;
   overflow: auto;
   overflow-y: overlap;
   position: relative;
}
```

A chat bubble container:

```
.chat-bubble-container {
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
}
```

And the chat bubbles (it just a "p" tag, not really part of the problem, so I did not put its code here).

In HTML, the chatbox look like this:

```
<!-- The chatbox -->

<div class="chatbox">

   <!-- The chat bubble container is wrapped inside the chatbox -->

   <div class="chat-bubble-container">

      <!-- Chat bubble will be created and put in here, I have already done that part -->

   </div>

</div>
```

- When new chat bubble is added, it appear at the bottom of the chatbox, and push older chat bubbles up, which make the chat bubble container scale upward.
- When the chat bubble container's height exceed the chatbox's height, it cause an overflow.
- But instead of making the scrollbar appear, the content inside the chatbox just being clipped.

So how do I resolve this?

Comment: What's this? `overflow-y: overlap;` - Is this something new? - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

Comment: I don't know, it from a tutorial long time ago. It make the overflow only show the vertical scrollbar.

Comment: `Overflow-y` is fine but there is no such value as `overlap`...try `auto` instead.

Comment: nothing really change after I switch from overlap to auto, not even the problem.

Comment: Then you'll need to demo the issue.

Comment: I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

Where the scrolling breaks is the  `position: absolute; bottom: 0;` on the `chat-bubble-container`.  If you remove the bottom requirement the scrollbars will show up.

Alternatively you could consider adding a fixed `height` and `overflow:scroll;` to the `.chat-bubble-container`